# How do I deploy application classes and Spring config files to Tomcat as a single jar?

Tags: spring-mvc, jar, tomcat7

Currently I create a new war file for each  change but the changes are taking place in only a few classes and the  Spring applicationContext.xml.
I would like to just update a jar file that  contains these classes and not continually re-deploy hundreds of files that have not changed.  I can create the  jar easily  enough but where do I  put it and do I  have to tell Spring to look in a specific jar for its' config files?

Comment: Madhead mentioned hot deployment, I was not asking  about  that.  I'm assuming a restart will be required.   I just  want to  put class files and Spring config files in a single jar.

Comment: Then adding custom loader may fit your needs. I've used this approach to create a web application with modular structure and plugins.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite impossible to hot-redeploy code in Tomcat without using extra tools like [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) [or custom JVM agents](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-loaded).

But it is possible to modularize you application by:

**1:** Putting JARs to `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib`. Never do this, this solution is good only for simple cases.

**2:** [Tune `context.xml`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html), [putting Loader in it](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/loader.html), like below:

```
    <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/">
        <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader" virtualClasspath="${catalina.base}/my-app-plugins/*.jar"/>
    </Context>
```

This will enable you putting JAR file in `$TOMCAT_HOME/my-app-plugins` and thet will be added to the classpath of you app. You should put `context.xml` to the `src/main/webapp/META-INF` folder (Maven layout). However, restart is still needed.

**3:** Use [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage). May be an overkill.